# Animating views with a timer

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer

I have an `NSTimer` where i'm doing simple movement of `UIImageView` for one place to another using physics formula, for timer functionality I used `NSTimer` like this,

```
//Timer starting
timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:0.03 target:self selector:@selector(elapse_time) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

In the `elapse_time` method i'm moving the object like,

```
myImageView_Object.frame = //Some CGRect value
```

Now I have more `myImageView`_Object in array I need to `setFrame` one by one for all `myImageView`_Object in array. How could I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The answers you have so far are just answering your question exactly, without trying to solve your problem.

You are moving a UIView. and you want to set it's position. And you are doing so at rather a high frequency. The real way to do this is with UIView animation. You give it a block and tell it how long the animation should take and you tell it what position it should be after the total time. It takes care of the tweening, and displaying for you. For example:

You want to move a UIView from it's original position to some new position in a time of, say, 3 seconds:

```
// Assume view1, view are UIView objects
view1.frame = // set initial frame
view2.frame = // set initial frame
view3.frame = // set initial frame

[UIView animateWithDuration:3.0 animations:^{
    view1.frame = // set final frame
    view2.frame = // ...
    view3.frame = == ...
}];
```

There are other variants of this that you can use, and you can find them in the [UIView Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html) under animation with Blocks